# Storing environment variables in a config file with fallback

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

At the moment I am using my environment variables as is, i.e., using `process.env.NODE_ENV` across my application, this works, but is becoming hard to keep track of, and I would therefore like to have all of these defined in a single file, ideally with fallbacks if the environment is not defined.

I tried creating a `config.js` file like

```
  export default ENVIROMENTS = {
  NODE: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  /* ... */
  }
```

and import it where needed, i.e

```
`import { ENVIROMENTS.NODE } from './config.js'`
```

But had no luck, with errors saying `ENVIROMENTS.NODE` is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not name your default export.

```
export default {
  NODE: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  /* ... */
}
```

and

```
import { NODE } from './config.js'
```